# Why didn't the D100, Godhead, and the Soul unlock?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I beat the Boss Rush and every major boss with every character but I'm still missing 5 items. I remember seeing "The D100 has appeared in the basement" as well as Godhead and the Soul but they aren't in my list. They aren't there but I know I beat it a day ago. It even shows that the post its for each character are all completed on hard mode.

What else do I need to do to unlock these items?

Comment: ...don't you have to collect the item once for it to appear in the list, not just unlock it?

Comment: I guess so. Ill keep playing and try to get angel rooms but I really hope I'm not wasting my time. I remember it saying has appeared in the basement. What you say makes sense. But are you sure about this? You don't seem 100%

Comment: @Powerlord That's precisely it. Why don't you turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 9):

You have to actually find the items in the dungeon for it to count.

Comment: @FrancoisBourbonnais You should accept the answer, then :)